# Repairing a rip in my hvac vent

Tags: hvac, ducts, hole-repair, duct-tape

A small section of canvas fabric connects the duct coming out of my furnace to the rest of the house. I noticed that there's quite a large rip in this fabric.
[image: Sizeable rip in the canvas]
 Would it be best to use standard foil tape to repair the rip, even though it'd be adhering to fabric and not metal? Is there another, better option?

Comment: It may be able to be repaired, I have seen these items for sale on the shelf at the big box stores. They will also be at HVAC supply houses As a mention, I think I would use a peel and stick like 9" wide Vycor would work for a good while, just wrap the whole area again

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a hard time getting foil tape to bond there, I think, and that component is designed to be flexible, partly for noise abatement. Foil would probably fail before long.

I'd cut a patch of heavy fabric (maybe marine vinyl) and bond it with a flexible adhesive--maybe 100% silicone. Clean the area and let it dry thoroughly first. Silicone would be set up enough to use in a couple hours. If there isn't too much movement when the furnace is running, the heat will speed things along. You could temporarily pad the patch with some soft foam or cloth secured with tape to hold the patch in place.

If the fabric is sound, and it's just a seam that has let loose, a little needlework might do as well.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on what to use to clean the fabric?

Comment: Mild soap and water.